# How do i resolve document is not defined error when using react router and nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-router

I am trying to use react router 6.4. I am using the newest layout , I even tried the older layout and I am still getting an error saying document is not defined.

How do I properly set up react router in a nextjs project. I am using it to render individual components on a page.

How do I define the document ?

I am using createBrowserRouter in the _app.js file

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
const router = createBrowserRouter({
basename: "/",
routeConfig: [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Splash,
  },
  {
    path: "/myaccount",
    component: MyAccount,
  },
  {
    path: "/profile",
    component: Profile,
  },
],
```

});

```
return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  </Provider>
);
```

}

export default MyApp;

this is the contents of my layout file

```
return (
<>
  <NavBar />
  {children}
</>
);
```

Comment: Why would wanna use React Router in a Next.js application and not use the built-in router?

Comment: I realised the error , I am new, basically what I am trying to achieve is to click on a side bar menu and render a component , but I only know how to do that in react router, Ive never done it in next js. I dont want to reload the page

Comment: You may wanna go through [his](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing). Next.js makes all this easier, the reason why people use it in the first place and not plain React.

Comment: I figured out a way how to achieve it using layout, but it still reloads my page, which I am trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Disabling file sytem router is available only if you are using pages router and not app router.

Check out - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server#disabling-file-system-routing

You can do

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
}
```